# Trying to evenly space out my nested view groups

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So here is a screenshot of how my layout looks like.  I'm using nested viewgroups for a book listing app.  All layouts, including the root layout, are Linear.  As you can see, I have 3 linear view groups in a horizontal orientation, each holding textviews in the vertical orientation.  I want the first LinearLayout at the left, the second one in the middle and the third one at the right, evenly spaced out.  At least that's what I've been trying to do.  I've been using layout gravity and weight but no luck.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyBdB.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Author(s)"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Publisher"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Publishing date"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Language"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Page count"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Print type"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Maturity rating"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second LinearLayout should have a width="match_parent", and the layout with weights should have a width of 0dp:

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Author(s)"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Publisher"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Publishing date"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Language"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Page count"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Print type"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Maturity rating"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So the left and the right linearlayout should get widths of 0dp and the middle layout get a widy of match-parent, am I correct?

Comment: Nope, all 3 should have widths of 0dp and equal weights (of 1). Check my edit of your code. It works.

Comment: Your solution did not work.  Perhaps I misunderstood what you were trying to imply.

Comment: It does.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you think my question was properly formatted for stackoverflow, do you mind giving it an upvote?